# Getting RabbitMQ message rates

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to an existing rabbit mq and get it's rates(or to it's exchange rates). Do I need to calculate the rates by myself or is there a simpler way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by rates?

Comment: The incoming/out massages per second

Comment: then check my answer, it is already there

Comment: [RabbitMQ Management HTTP Stats](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.19/priv/www/doc/stats.html)

Answer (score 2):

I used this way:

```
curl -i -u user:pass 'http://server_ip:server_port/api/queues?sort=message_stats.publish_details.rate&sort_reverse=true&columns=name,message_stats.publish_details.rate,message_stats.deliver_get_details.rate,messages,messages_ready,memory,state'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) which is included in the RabbitMQ distribution:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Then you can access the Web UI at `http://server-name:15672/` where you can find the message rates along with other useful info such as established queues/exchanges, their activity, vhosts etc.

The data is also made available via the REST API at `http://server-name:15672/api/`. Basic Authentication with a default guest user is enabled on plugin activation (the user should be changed).

For example, to get a list of established exchanges with their inbound/outbound message rates, sorted in descending order by outbound rates, you can make a following GET request:

http://USER:PASS@SERVER:15672/api/exchanges/VHOST?sort=message_stats.publish_out_details.rate&sort_reverse=true&columns=name,message_stats.publish_in_details.rate,message_stats.publish_out_details.rate

Which returns the data in following format:

```
[
  {
    "message_stats": {
      "publish_in_details": {
        "rate": 1.4
      },
      "publish_out_details": {
        "rate": 5
      }
    },
    "name": "some.exchange"
  },
  ...
]
```

You can also get the averages for specific time ranges. For example, this:
http://USER:PASS@SERVER:15672/api/exchanges/VHOST?msg_rates_age=3600&msg_rates_incr=60
will return the last hour's data on queue message rates, with a sample for every minute (the `message_stats` property will be extended with averages).

Look at [this](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_14/priv/www/doc/stats.html) for more info on `message_stats` and `_details`

Comment: I'm not sure if the management plugin is already enabled. Is there a way to check it?
Also could you elaborate on how do i access to the web?
If it's not clear I wish to get the rates for my own winforms GUI. Thanks.

Comment: You can SSH into your RabbitMQ server and then run `sudo rabbitmq-plugins list | grep rabbitmq_management`. You should see a list of management plugins where either _E*_ or _e*_ is in angle brackets if they're enabled.

Comment: Also, if you plan to use this information in your own app, then you should use the REST API. I'll edit the post with an example

Comment: Ok if it's enabled. Can you give an exaple on how to access to the web and the queue rates. Sorry for the milking. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post with an example of how to call the API to get the rates for a given exchange. For more info, refer to the API documentation

Comment: I've edited again with an example for defining time frames with averages for minute samples.